# How to join the indexing in np.where?

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
ind1 = np.where(a>8)
ind2 = np.where(a<3)
```

What I want is [1,2,9,10].

At this time, How to join the two index, 'ind1' and 'ind2'?

When I face the situation like this, I just wrote the code like below,

```
ind3 = np.where( (a>8) & (a<3) )
```

But if I face the more complex situation, I can not use the above code.

So I want to know the method which can find the index joining 'ind1' and 'ind2' directly, not fixing inside of 'np.where()'.

=================================

Sorry, I mistook but already there is a good answer, so I will not erase my original question.

What I mean is below,

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
ind1 = np.where(a>8)
ind2 = np.where(a>3)
```

What I want to expect is [9,10].
i.e. I want to intersection.

Comment: Boolean operators between conditions are not limited to one. You can use as much as you need. Can you include an example where you *can not use the above code*? The example code (yields `[]`) doesn't match your expected result. Did you mean to use `|`?

Comment: What do you mean by `complex situation`??? Your proposed method get empty array not your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using Boolean mask arrays:

```
ind1 = a > 8
ind2 = a < 3
ind3 = np.logical_or(ind1, ind2)
print(a[ind3])   # --> [ 1  2  9 10]
```

If you have more than two condition:

```
ind_n = np.logical_or.reduce((ind1, ind2, ind3, ...))
```

For using `np.where`, you must change your proposed code to:

```
ind3 = np.where((a > 8) | (a < 3))
```

Comment: could you sum indexes using np.where?

Comment: @BAO, what do you mean by `sum`? get an example

Comment: You use 'ind1 = a > 8, ind2 = a < 3', but I want to know about 'ind1 = np.where(a>8), ind2 = np.where(a<3)'. Could you find union using  'ind1 = np.where(a>8), ind2 = np.where(a<3)'?

Comment: And also I want to know how to fine intersect of  'ind1 = np.where(a>8), ind2 = np.where(a>3)'

Comment: @BAO If you want to use  `ind1 = np.where(a > 8)` and `ind2 = np.where(a > 3)` --> `np.intersect1d(ind1, ind2)`

Answer (score 2):

Why not do a for loop?

```
idx = []
for i in range X:
  idx.append(np.where(some condition))

results = np.concat(idx)
```

Comment: The title is about joining indices in `np.where`.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [41]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
    ...: ind1 = np.where(a > 8)
    ...: ind2 = np.where(a > 3)
    ...:
```

First, make sure you understand what each `where/nonzero` produces:

```
In [42]: ind1, ind2
Out[42]: ((array([8, 9]),), (array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),))
```

That's a tuple with one array (since `a` is 1d).

We can extract that array:

```
In [43]: ind1[0], ind2[0]
Out[43]: (array([8, 9]), array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

`numpy` set operations aren't that great.  But we can use Python sets:

```
In [45]: set(ind1[0]), set(ind2[0])
Out[45]: ({8, 9}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9})
In [46]: set(ind1[0]).intersection(set(ind2[0]))
Out[46]: {8, 9}
```

Doing logical operations on the boolean inputs to where is usually a better choice.

We could test the 2 arrays for equality:

```
In [50]: ind1[0][:, None] == ind2[0]
Out[50]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True]])
In [52]: (ind1[0][:, None] == ind2[0]).any(axis=0)
Out[52]: array([False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True])
In [53]: ind2[0][(ind1[0][:, None] == ind2[0]).any(axis=0)]
Out[53]: array([8, 9])
```